# Any reason why someone would use printf() for pretty much everything?

Tags: php, mysql, validation, variables, printf

I am taking over a project from an existing programmer who, to be honest, left the project in a massive heap of unmaintainable, unreadable mess (**edit/clarification:** dozens upon dozens of standalone .php pages that are a soup of php/html/css that all reference one giant 1500 line 'functions.php' file, ack)

That being said, it seems that pretty much everywhere there is a variable, array, etc. he used printf().

For example, instead of using:

```
foreach($thing as $t) {
    echo "<option value='".$t."'>".$t."</option>";
}
```

He would use something like:

```
foreach($thing as $t) {
     printf("<option value='%s'>%s</option>", $t, $t);
}
```

Does anyone have any insight as to why exactly he would do this? Is there some unknown benefit that I am not aware of by using printf() instead of echo/print?

Please note that this isn't just for values that might need to be validated/scrubbed, but for EVERYTHING. Data pulled from the database, random variables and arrays that were defined elsewhere, absolutely everything is printf() instead of just echo or print, and i'm trying to figure out why he would use this method as it might help me understand the logic behind some of the things he built.

Comment: Maybe for an override at some point to output translations?

Comment: A good point, but nothing is translated in this project at all... one language start to finish.

Comment: While conversing with a crusty old C programmer a few weeks ago, I was amused to learn that he uses printf for everything, even when he dabbles in PHP. Could it be that your predecessor came from another language background and never fully learned PHP?

Comment: It might just be tidier, because you can immediately spot the variables. Also, you don't need to worry about escaping deeply nested array keys. Finally, you can use an unparsed string (`''`) rather than a parsed string (`""`) for a bit of extra performance, or at least control.

Comment: I've edited your code to make for a more fare comparison. Your original code samples seemed to imply that `printf` was substantially longer and more complex, while in actuality you were generating a more complex output with the `printf` version. Now they do the same thing, and you can see there is very little difference in the visual complexity of the line, possibly less.

Comment: @KerrekSB Interesting point - that would be a valid point, although most of the variables are pretty simple strings. 

I'm leaning towards the PHP-from-a-book explanation based on his limited exposure to any programming language previous to this particular project.

Comment: @JonathanCoe: The question "why did **he** do it that way" is for you to decide; I just gave some ideas on why it might seem like a good idea...

Comment: @KerrekSB A good summary - I think i'm just trying to clarify if there is some hidden reason i'm missing other than personal preference of the previous guy. Thanks for the insight :)

Comment: @Jonathan There is no reason other than personal preference. It could be that there are places he used more advanced string formatting, and wanted to consistently use `printf` through out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"The only reason to use printf() in preference over echo or print() is if you will be using the format string place-holders feature with additional arguments (one for each such place-holder). If not, then print() will be faster, and echo even (very slightly) faster since it does not generate a return value."

Found here: [echo VS printf](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=130936)

Comment: Interesting read... i've been doing some digging on sprintf/printf since starting this project as it's not something i've ever seen a reason to use before.... to me any benefit is quickly outweighed by the mess-of-symbols look it gives pages where it is used a lot - which makes me start to question if this guy knows something I don't.

Answer (score 4):

I imagine he did it for code read-ability. I think using printf/sprintf is more readable than 
embedding variables directly into string and alternating `'"""''""''"`.

Personally I think this is the most readable method:

```
<?php foreach($thing as $t): ?>
     <option value="<?php echo $t ?>"><?php echo $t ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

It has the added benefit of looking nice in most IDEs

Comment: 100% agree.  I never really liked all of the dot (.) concatenation that ends up in php code.  But then I come from a pascal / c background.

Comment: I agree this is much cleaner when embedding PHP directly into html. I'm starting to think that perhaps it is purely readability - for him anyways.

Comment: I'm not particularly fond of the multiple `<?php echo $t; ?>` parts, but that has been a necessary evil due to unknown short tag options per server. Fortunately, in PHP 5.4 the `<?= $t ?>` echo shorthand will be available regardless of whether short tags `<? ?>` are enabled. Then we can confidently use the cleaner `<?= ?>` when it's all that is needed.

Comment: Ugh. How is expanding a simple `%s` to a huge `<?php echo $t ?>` context switch more readable? The amount of extra punctuation on that line renders it almost impossible to tell at a glance what is going on.

Comment: @meagar I think it boils down to consistency - I think <?php echo $foo.$bar; ?> is much more readable than <?php printf(%s%s,$foo,$bar); ?> as the printf method for longer concanted strings requires me to figure out which variable belongs to which %s. But again, as I think this post is showing me, it does start to boil down to personal preference for line readability.

Comment: @Jonathan Nobody ever suggested using printf to concatenate two strings. That's just silly.

Comment: I tend to prefer using a template engine, and keep pure business logic in my php and display logic in my template.

Comment: @Scuzzy - You can do that with my method and no extra layer. PHP is a template engine.

Comment: @meagar yep... using sprintf to concatenate a bunch of strings is pretty silly. Let me tell you.

Answer (score 2):

Well i would have definitely used `printf` in your example. I often use `printf`, `sprintf`, or `strtr` when outputting html elements with a lot of attributes or complex ones. Its just more readable and its much easier to swap out the values later.